# Current to voltage converter with signal at non inverting terminal

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, design

I'm studying the following current to voltage converter:

[image]

The output should be:

$$V_{ADC2}=-Z \, I_Z - V_{WE2}$$

with \$Z=\frac{R}{RCs+1}\$.
Why there is the input \$V_{WE2}\$? What is its role?

The whole circuit in which there is the above I-V convert (and there is also another I-V converter, always with voltage at non inverting terminal) is:

[image]

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Its role is to provide a reference voltage. It is added to Vadc2 to shift the voltage either up or down. Typically these are used with a 2.5V reference to shift a bipolar signal (like ±2.5) to a 0 to 5V range for the ADC (which are typically 5V)

It doesn't have to be 2.5V, it could be 0V (no shift) or another value, usually within the rails of the opamp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEU4wc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>